# How do you search part of a name within a table?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table of names (e.g: Peter de San Marino) within a database, I'm trying to search and display the results of status of application on a page. If a user type just Peter and hit the search button to know if his application is ready either lower or uppercase, the full name with the status should be displayed.

Much appreciated.
Don

Comment: You could find a name like "San Marino" with the command `select * from names where last_name like '%mar%';`  This would find "San Marino", "san mArInO" ... and "Marin", "Martino" and "MaryKnoll" as well.

Comment: please add table structure and query details.. also provide whta you have tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE names LIKE '%name%'
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$name = 'Peter de San Marino';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
} else {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['RelevantTableColumn'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```